# Custom html on top of JW Player fullscreen

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jwplayer

I need to display html on top of JW Player, even when it's fullscreen. The way I'm trying to do it now is by inserting my html inside jw player container with jquery. This works but my styles are overridden by the ones jw player inserts through it's script. I would like to know either a way to prevent this from happening or a different way to overlap my html.

Comment: Are you trying to do this in Flash or HTML5 mode?

Comment: HTML5. I was able to use `getComputedStyle` to get the original styles of every element before appending them to the player, and it works. But now I'm trying to figure out how to get the hover styles working also. Anyways, I would like to know if there's a better to do this.

Comment: With the JW Player, there is a way to do this by making a custom plugin, which already has it's own built in resize methods. https://github.com/jwplayer/jwplayer-sdks/tree/master/jw6-plugin-sdk